# ElasticSearch API POST/PUT DeDupe

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to use the Elastic Search RESTful API to send data to my ES instance. Here is some sample data:

```
[{"subject":"matt","predicate":"likes","object":"coffee","label":"1_10"}]
[{"subject":"james","predicate":"likes","object":"water","label":"1_10"}]
[{"subject":"leo","predicate":"likes","object":"liquor","label":"1_10"}]
[{"subject":"matt","predicate":"likes","object":"coffee","label":"1_10"}]
[{"subject":"matt","predicate":"likes","object":"coffee","label":"1_10"}]
```

My post call looks like:

```
"http://" + url + "/something/quads/
```

With the JSON payload.

I was looking at a put call and was trying the following:

```
"http://" + url + "/something/quads/_create
```

from this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/create-doc.html

The problem is that it created the ID in ES as _create Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use POST calls with URLs like `/something/quads/` then ES will automatically generate IDs for your documents.

If, instead, you want to use PUT calls, you need to provide document IDs yourself in the URL `/something/quads/123`, `/something/quads/456`, etc.

In your second URL `/something/quads/_create`, you're missing the document ID. It should be `/something/quads/123/_create`. Check the docs you've linked to again and you'll see.

Also note that the difference between the two following commands

```
PUT /something/quads/123
PUT /something/quads/123/_create
```

is that the second will fail if a document with the ID `123` already exists. The first command, however, will always succeed and overwrite the document with ID `123` if one exists.

Comment: Is there a way to do Dedupe on just the JSON record itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain a little bit?